# Combine two text files with integers into one text file

Tags: java

I need to combine two text files into one merged text file. The files only consist of numbers, and the numbers must then be listed in ascending order. I have coded it to do this, however, I can't get it to add the last number and it gives me a numberformatexception error. I believe this is because my last number doesn't have anything to compare it to so I can't add it to the list. I'm not sure how to add the last number when it has nothing to compare itself too (I'm pretty sure I need another if statement i'm just not sure how to do it) and I dont know what the right while statement is, however the program is running correctly with the while statement I used, sans the last number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    FileReader file1         = null;
    FileReader file2         = null;
    BufferedReader readfile1 = null;
    BufferedReader readfile2 = null;
    FileWriter fileout       = null;
    PrintWriter dataout;
    String fname1         = "list1.txt";
    String fname2         = "list2.txt";
    int md                   = 0;
    int file1num             = 0;
    int file2num             = 0;
    String file1str;
    String file2str;

    try
      {
        file1 = new FileReader(fname1);
      }
    catch
        (FileNotFoundException xyz)
      {
        System.out.println("File not found: " + fname1);
        System.exit(-1);
      }
    catch
        (IOException abc)
      {
        System.out.println("IOException: caught");
        System.exit(-1);
      }
    readfile1 = new BufferedReader(file1);
    try
                  {
                    readfile2 = new FileReader(fname2);
                  }
    catch
                  (FileNotFoundException xyz)
                  {
                    System.out.println("File not found: " + fname2);
                    System.exit(-1);
                  }
                 catch
                  (IOException abc)
                  {
                    System.out.println("IOException: caught");
                    System.exit(-1);
                  }
                 readfile2 = new BufferedReader(file2);
                 try
                   {
                     fileout = new FileWriter("merged.txt");
                   }
                 catch(IOException adc)
                   {
                     System.out.println("file error");
                     System.exit(-1);
                   }
                 dataout = new PrintWriter(fileout);
                 file1str = file1.readLine();
                 file1num = Integer.parseInt(file1str);
                 file2str = file2.readLine();
                 file2num = Integer.parseInt(file2str);
                 while(md !=-1)
                   {
                     if(file1num<file2num)
                       {
                         md=file1num;
                         file1str = file1.readLine();
                         file1num = Integer.parseInt(file1str);
                       }
                     if(file2num<file1num)
                       {
                         md=file2num;
                         file2str = file2.readLine();
                         file2num = Integer.parseInt(file2str);
                       }
                     if(file1num==file2num)
                       {
                         md=file1num;
                         file1str = file1.readLine();
                         file1num = Integer.parseInt(file1str);
                       }
    }
```

So I know that after the last int from file 1 is read it will come back with a null, which means that file 2 can't compare itself to anything else, and I believe that is where my problem is coming from. The problem is with the while statement and what is contained in it. Also I can't use any arrays or anything like that, it has to be a simple read the two files, compare, add the lowest number to the merge file.

**Example input:**

file1:

```
1
2 
3 
4 
6 
8
```

file2:

```
3 
5 
6 
8
9
```

**Expected output:**

```
1
2
3
3
4
5
6
6
8
8
9
```

Comment: You should provide an example of two input files and an expected output file

Comment: Is this all of the code? Where do you generate the output?

Comment: the output is put into the 3rd merged file. @alfasin I can't figure out where there is an attachment button, but for example file one would be 1 2 3 4 6 8 9 and file two would be 3 5 6 8 9 (one number per line). The expectd output would be 1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 8 8 9 (again 1 number per line).

Comment: If this is not a class exercise, this can be easily accomplished with the `sort` command.

Comment: It looks like it would be much easier to read these two files into one `ArrayList<Integer>` (for example) and then use `Collections.sort()`

Comment: I'm not allowed to use sort or arrays.

Comment: Then use two Lists and merge them like it's done in merge sort (second part of the algorithm).

Comment: You should print out a stack trace in your `catch` blocks.  In fact, you should have your try-catch block surrounding all the code; since you exit from each block, there's no need to have more than one catch block of each type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to consider what to do when one file, or the other, runs out.

BufferedReader.readLine() returns a null on EOF, so you'll be looking for nulls.

The logic looks something like this

```
str1 = read file1
num1 = parse( str1 ) //parse() should be a method that can properly handle a null 
str2 = read file2    //and return something appropriate, like -1, when null 
num2 = parse( str2 ) //is encountered

while str1 != null || str2 != null

    if str2 == null || num1 < num2
        write num1
        str1 = read file1
        num1 = parse( str1 )
    else if str1 == null || num1 > num2
        write num2
        str2 = read file2
        num2 = parse( str2 )
    else if num1 == num2
        write num1
        write num2
        str1 = read file1
        num1 = parse( str1 )
        str2 = read file2
        num2 = parse( str2 )
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, the only thing I had to add was a nested if statement within each one so that if str1 was null it would not do num1= parse(str1)

Answer (score 0):

you try to use `trim()` `Integer.parseInt(blabla.trim());` Because your digits have one or more space characters so parse wasn't succeed .

example code :

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

```
File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\Melih\\Desktop\\file1.txt");
File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Melih\\Desktop\\file2.txt");
File output = new File("C:\\Users\\Melih\\Desktop\\file3.txt");

BufferedReader file1Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
BufferedReader file2Reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output);

String file1Num = file1Reader.readLine();
String file2Num = file2Reader.readLine();

while (file1Num != null && file2Num != null) {
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(file1Num.trim());
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(file2Num.trim());

    if (num1 < num2) {
        writer.println(num1);
        file1Num = file1Reader.readLine();

    } else if (num2 < num1) {
        writer.println(num2);
        file2Num = file2Reader.readLine();
    } else {
        writer.println(num1);
        file1Num = file1Reader.readLine();
    }
}
while (file1Num != null) {

    writer.println(file1Num);
    file1Num = file1Reader.readLine();
}
while (file2Num != null) {
    writer.println(file2Num);
    file2Num = file2Reader.readLine();
}
file1Reader.close();
file2Reader.close();
writer.close();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have two lists that hold the Integer values of the first and the second files, 
if you'll read both files into Lists, say lst1 and lst2 then the merge into lst3 should be easy:

```
Integer a1 = null;
Integer a2 = null;
while (!lst1.isEmpty() || !lst2.isEmpty()){
    try{
      a1 = (Integer)lst1.remove(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    try{
      a2 = (Integer)lst2.remove(0);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}

    if(a1 == null && a2 != null) lst3.add(a2);
    else if(a1 != null && a2 == null) lst3.add(a1);
    else{
        while(a1 < a2){
           lst3.add(a1);
           try{
               a1 = (Integer)lst1.remove(0);
           }        
           catch(Exception e){break;}  
        }
        while(a1 >= a2){
           lst3.add(a2);
           try{
               a2 = (Integer)lst2.remove(0);
           }        
           catch(Exception e){break;}  
        }     
        while(a1 != null && lst2.isEmpty()){
           lst3.add(a1);
           try{
               a1 = (Integer)lst1.remove(0);
           }        
           catch(Exception e){break;}  
        }   
        while(a2 != null && lst1.isEmpty()){
           lst3.add(a2);
           try{
               a2 = (Integer)lst2.remove(0);
           }        
           catch(Exception e){break;}  
        }        
    }    
}
```

Then you can write the content of `lst3` into the output file.
*Disclaimer*: I wrote the code using notepad - you'll probably have to "patch" it a bit ;)